# How to show array elements at once (at the position %d)

Tags: c

I want to make an empty array with size (like x and z below)
--> fill array with elements by looping only (not by scanf, getchar(), or manually type elements in the arrays)
--> and then print out the elements in one line, for example:
"Even numbers are: 2,4,6,8,10,12,14,20"  <-- this is the result I want to get.

I would really appreciate it if you help with this!

The below is what I did so far.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
        int i,j;
        int x[ 30 ];
        char b[ 30 ];

        for (i = 1; i<=20; i++){
                if(i%2 ==0){
                        x[i] = i;
                        sprintf(b, " %d ", x[i]);
                        printf("Even nums are: %s ", b);
                }
        }
}
```

so far, I made the array to take 'i's in the loop as its elements. After that, I tried to join char array to one statement or like, char[0] = "2,4,6,8 ..." but couldn't make it.

Comment: Is it important to store each number in an array? Would you settle for simply printing the output that you want: "_Even numbers are: 2,4,6,8,10,12,14,20_"?

Comment: First of all there's no need for any arrays here. Secondly, remember that array indexes start at zero, using one-based indexing will make your code look weird and be a surprise for others looking at the code.

Comment: As for how to solve your problem, the `strcat` function might be useful to use. But remember two things: 1) It requires the destination string to be an actual initialized null-terminate string, your array `b` is not that; And 2) Make sure you know how many characters will be added to the string, and resize if accordingly (and remember the space needed for the null-terminator).

Answer (score 3):

Acting on the assumption that there's no need for the individual values to be stored, it's simple to just build up the string that you say you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) {
    char str[ 100 ], *at = str; // Generous buffer and a pointer to its beginning

    at += sprintf( at, "Even nums are: " ); // Load the output prefix

    char *sep = ""; // initially NO separator

    for( int i = 2; i <= 20; i += 2 ) { // Count 2 -> 20 by 2's
        at += sprintf( at, "%s%d", sep, i ); // append to growing string
        sep = ", "; // subsequent values preceded by separator
    }

    // output
    puts( str );

    return 0;
}
```

```
Even nums are: 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20
```

Comment: May be worth noting that a check on `at - str < 11 + 1` (in the general case for max chars in `int` with `+/-` and the nul-character, or use the `snprintf (NULL, 0, ...)` trick) would ensure you don't write beyond the end of `str` if the numbers used are not known. Worst case, 10 - `int` could require `110 + 1 + 27 = 138 chars` (max digits with `+/-` plus nul-character plus 27 sep chars). Utilizes `at` as an additional check. (your example is fine for evens up to `20`)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin You're quite right! A "generous" buffer, used here, is nothing more than a guess that has been "rounded up". Were this more than a mere demonstration of this technique to produce a string, proper attention must be paid to its ultimate length. Thank you for pointing this out. `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

C does not automatically add a newline at the end of printf statements, so you could simply have a print statement for every number individually with commas before (except for the first value, where there shouldn't be a comma at the beginning).

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int i;
        
    printf("Even nums are: ");
    for (i = 1; i<=20; i++){
        if(i%2 ==0){
            if (i == 2)
                printf("%d", i);
            else
                printf(", %d", i);
        }
    }
}
```

You don't need a list, but if you want to do this in two separate for loops, just have the first for loop assign each even number to a list like you did in your code, then have the second for loop do the printf statements by indexing the list.

Comment: There should probably be a `putchar('\n');` or something equivalent after the loop completes.  Make sure you always produce lines with a newline at the end.

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one way to solve this.

First, let's to the lazy approach:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    const int MAX_SIZE = 30;
    int store_even[MAX_SIZE];
    
    printf("Even number are: ");
    for (int i = 0, value = 2; i < MAX_SIZE; ++i, value+=2){
        store_even[i] = value;
        printf("%d ", store_even[i]);
    }
}
```

We eliminated the variable `b` since we don't needed in order to print the results.

```
Even number are: 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 40 42 44 46 48 50 52 54 56 58 60
```

However, we still have room for improvement here. That extra variable `value` is bothersome. Can we do it with just the index? Sure we can! By using some little math:

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    const int MAX_SIZE = 30;
    int store_even[MAX_SIZE];
    
    printf("Even number are: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; ++i){
        store_even[i] = (i * 2) + 2;
        printf("%d ", store_even[i]);
    }
}
```

The `+2` allow us to set the first even number correctly.

If we run this we get:

```
Even number are: 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 40 42 44 46 48 50 52 54 56 58 60
```

If by any chance you still want to store the integers as strings, let me know and I can change my answer to accommodate your requirement.